# Allow users to download only once

Tags: java, sqlite, jsp

A web app, the client side is jsp and backend is JAVA, DB is simple sqlite. 
In the DB there is a table that contains "files" called Reports, and users are allowed to download each file in the DB only ONCE "Due to security requirements", and I have been trying to find a way to do that.
Is there anyway I can write a jsp code that allows the users to download the requested file once from the DB?

I don't know if it is useful but this is the JAVA piece of code that is used to download from the DB.

```
String sql = "SELECT file, filename FROM reports INNER JOIN download USING(tipid) WHERE reports.tipid = ?"+
                "AND download.ts_" + ae_num+ " = 0;";

        PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
        String tipNum = request.getParameter("tipid");
        if (tipNum != null) {

            stmt.setString(1, tipNum);
            //stmt.setString(2, tipNum);
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
            BufferedInputStream fileBlob = null;
            String filename = "";

            while (res.next()) {
                fileBlob = new BufferedInputStream(res.getBinaryStream("file"), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

                filename = res.getString("filename");
            }
            if (fileBlob != null) {
                System.out.println(filename);
                response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

                BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),
                        DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
                int length;
                while ((length = fileBlob.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                output.close();
                fileBlob.close();
                Date now = new Date();

                sql = "UPDATE download SET ts_" + ae_num + " = " + now.getTime() + " WHERE tipid = ?;";
                System.out.println(sql);
                stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1, tipNum);

                stmt.executeUpdate();
                stmt.close();

                c.commit();
                c.close();
```

The current problem I'm having is that whenever a user is trying to download the requested file and whether the user chose to open/save or cancel, it will be counted as a downloaded file, even with a cancel.

Any ideas? Would using cookies in JSP help to implement that? If so can someone guide me? Or how to solve the download count issue

Comment: Cookies are never a good idea for anything regarding prevention; they're ridiculously easy to circumvent. It looks like you're already tracking when the user downloads something via the `download` table; have the code which processes your downloads check to see if a previous download event has been tracked, and if so, redirect to an error page.

Comment: When you say 'users are allowed to download each file in the DB only ONCE ', how do you define a user? Users are identified with a login/password or do you have to make assumptions based on the IP or something like that?

Comment: And how do you define a download? What happens if the browser was disconnected after downloading half the file? What happens if the user starts two downloads in parallel?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja True, but I have an issue when the user is prompted to save/open or cancel downloading the file, even if the choice was "cancel", it will be counted as a downloaded and user won't be allowed to request that file again

Comment: @RealSkeptic it will be counted as downloaded and that is an issue I'm trying to figure out

Comment: But if user did not download on first time, he can never download.

Comment: Ok. Your code block seems to fine. What is the issue?

Comment: @sunrise76 exactly, that is the big issue I'm having, any tips or ideas how to prevent that from happening ?
If user chose to cancel and not to download the file, he won't be able to redownload it again

Comment: After going through the code, I realized that things will work as expected. If user did not complete the download, update query does not execute

Comment: @sunrise76 I've worked on a similar issue; our implementation uses a code solution (counts number of available downloads per user per file) and a business solution (if user download fails, we provide a help option to request additional downloads, in which download count gets decremented by 1, plus each request is tracked).

Comment: @sunrise76 for some reason this part of code 
  while (res.next()) {
                fileBlob = new BufferedInputStream(res.getBinaryStream("file"), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

                filename = res.getString("filename");
            }

Will start saving the file and mark it as downloaded once the user hit the download button, and before the user chooses whether to save/open or cancel ..

Comment: @WT86 Yeah, that makes sense; you don't get feedback from the browser when/whether a file is done downloading (unless you're using Flash to download or something).

Comment: Is there a way around this ? Or do we have to just deal with it?

Comment: Well, I guess then I have to either use flash, or just deal with it :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the database, you could possibly have another table with the user_id, file_id, download_status column. That way you could always have the records who downloaded the file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have a table in the DB that shows what files the users downloaded :)